# Example of a module which is left projective and right flat?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I'm looking for an example of a surjective ring homomorphism $\alpha: R \to S$ such that $S$ is a projective left $R$-module and a flat right $R$-module but $S$ is not a projective right $R$-module.